# Edit control cannot get focus or set text after subclassing

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing, editbox, edit-control

I had created an editbox and it was working just fine but after I added a custom WndProc for it, the text "my edit" is not visible and won't take focus when clicked.

```
HWND handle=CreateWindowExW(0,L"Edit",L"my edit",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_CENTER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
                         0,0,200,200,window.handle,0,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);
```

Until here it was working just fine
After I set this window procedure, the edit control is not working anymore as expected

```
SetWindowLongPtr(handle,GWLP_WNDPROC,(LRESULT)staticWndProc); 
LRESULT CALLBACK staticWndProc(HWND handle, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (uMsg){
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            std::wcout << handle << L" click\n"; //click event works
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProcW(handle,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

Do I have to handle manually some event or change my construction style flags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sub-classing involves intercepting messages for a window, possibly handling some of them, and passing those you don't handle to the **original window procedure**.

You're not doing that - you're passing everything you don't handle through to `DefWindowProc`. `DefWindowProc` doesn't have any of the specialised behaviour for an edit control (or indeed for any type of control). So you've effectively turned an edit control into a generic window.

Using `SetWindowLongPtr` to sub-class a window is discouraged these days, but if you do use that method, the return value from the call to `SetWindowLongPtr` gives you the old window procedure, and you're meant to use the `CallWndProc` function instead of `DefWindowProc` to call it.

However, the modern way to subclass a window is using the `SetWindowSubclass` function, which handles calling the original proc for you - all you need to do is call the `DefSubclassProc` function, as shown here:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK staticWndProc(HWND handle, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR){
    switch (uMsg){
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            std::wcout << handle << L" click\n"; //click event works
            break;
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            RemoveWindowSubclass(handle, staticWndProc, 0);
            // fall through
        default:
            return DefSubclassProc(handle,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
    }
    return 0;  
}

SetWindowSubclass(handle, staticWndProc, 0, 0);
```

Note that the subclass function shown above removes itself when `WM_NCDESTROY` is received.

Comment: That works fine, thanks! I thought it was ok to leave a single window procedure with DefWindowProcW but apparently I still needed that CallWndProc.